# R contour and fill contour can't fit together

Tags: r, contour

I wana to draw a picture of global sea surface temperature ,but after I filled the contour of the sst, I try to add counter broader onto the filled picture,then some strange happened, these tow picture can't fit together 
here is the code, because I have no room to put the original data ,a random number is used

here is the code

```
library(maps)

ee<-array(rnorm(89*180),dim=c(89,180))

lati <- seq(-90,90,length=89) #Latitudes goes from -90 to 90 as far as I know :)
long <- seq(-180,180,length=180)
plot(NA, xlim=c(-180,180), ylim=c(-90,90), xlab="", ylab="", xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
contour(long, lati, t(ee), add=TRUE)
filled.contour(long,lati,t(ee), color.palette=terrain.colors)
maps::map(database="world", fill=TRUE, col="light blue", add=TRUE)
```

as we see, the filled picture's position is not corresponding with the original data
such as the only contour pic

what is the problem?

at last  sorry for my poor English, thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the following in th `filled.contour` help page :

> The output produced by ‘filled.contour’ is actually a combination of
>   two plots; one is the filled contour and one is the legend. Two
>   separate coordinate systems are set up for these two plots, but they
>   are only used internally - once the function has returned these
>   coordinate systems are lost.  If you want to annotate the main contour
>   plot, for example to add points, you can specify graphics commands in
>   the ‘plot.axes’ argument.  See the examples.

So, trying to apply this to your example, you can do something like :

```
library(maps)
ee<-array(rnorm(89*180),dim=c(89,180))
lati <- seq(-90,90,length=89) #Latitudes goes from -90 to 90 as far as I know :)
long <- seq(-180,180,length=180)
draw.map <- function() {maps::map(database="world", fill=TRUE, col="light blue", add=TRUE)}
filled.contour(long,lati,t(ee), color.palette=terrain.colors, plot.axes=draw.map())
```

Which gives :

[image]

Comment: thank you juba   As a new here  I am very happy that you can help me with all these question

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If my answer solved your problem, you can check the green mark to make it known to other users. But you can also wait for other and maybe better answers.

Comment: ok but my reputation is too low to do it  I will try my best to do something I am good at such as FORTRAN or Meteorology